# How to get skinurl in Magento2

Tags: magento2

What is replacement  function for getting the skinurl in magento-2. In magento-1 we use  `$this->getSkinUrl()` and  `{{skin url=''}}` to get skin url.

Answer (score 36, accepted):

**in magento 1**

```
$this->getSkinUrl()
```

**Replace with in magento2**

```
$block->getViewFileUrl()
```

**in magento 1**

```
{{skin url=''}}
```

**Replace with in magento2**

```
{{view url=''}}
```

[Reference](https://blog.qaisarsatti.com/magento_2/magento2-get-static-url-or-skin-url/)

Comment: Does not explain how to fetch it from inside a template used by any block type

Comment: @OZZIE every block file `extends` from `Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template`  that `extends` with  `Magento\Framework\View\Element\AbstractBlock.php`. you can on line  `762` you can this method `getViewFileUrl`